# SSIS package will not run on server, but works fine on Dev machine

Tags: oracle, ssis, etl, attunity

I am using Attunity drivers to connect to an Oracle source through SSIS in order to publish to my SQL Server (2019)

The package runs just fine on my laptop in VS2019 and publishes to SSIS catalog on my server

When I try to execute the package I get the following errors though

[image]

Our IT dep states that they have installed the same attunity drivers as I have (All 64 bit also on my laptop)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm an idiot

The SSIS instance I have does not run on our Enterprise license but out standard license.

Attunity drivers are only available to enterprise SSIS, and everything else oracle --> SQL Server is too slow over the linked server queries I run now